# Trying to send data from one electron window to another via ipc

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

Building my first electron app and I'd like the workflow to be as follows:

mainWindow opens -> user clicks 'open' button -> 2nd window opens -> user enters input/hits submit -> mainWindow opens back up displaying user input

Below is my `app.on('ready'`) from my `main.js`. The application startup (`win.loadURL`) works fine, as does the `open-new-window` event. The weirdness comes in the `input-broadcast`.

When the user enters input in the second window, the main window will re-open. However, the text in the `console.log` in the `input-broadcast` does not appear, and the `input-received` never fires in the main window's renderer.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, however I may be using the wrong design pattern as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, remote} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const countdown = require('./countdown');

let win;
const windows = [];

app.on('ready', () =>{
console.log('app ready');

ipcMain.on('open-new-window', () =>{
    console.log('trying to open window');
        win.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'enterValue.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }));
});

ipcMain.on('input-broadcast', (evt, data) =>{
    console.log('input-broadcast happened in main');
    win.webContents.send('input-received', data);
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));      
});

win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
win.on('closed', () =>{
    console.log('closed');
    win = null;
});
})
```

**renderer.js (assoc. with the index.html)**

```
console.log('from renderer1');

const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window');
    console.log('window button clicked');
});

ipcRenderer.on('open-new-window', (evt, count) =>{
    document.getElementById('userInput').innerHTML(count);
});

ipcRenderer.on('input-received', (evt, data) =>{
    console.log('input received');
    console.log(evt);
    console.log(data);
});
```

**renderer2.js (assoc. with the user enterValue.html)**

```
console.log('from renderer2');

const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', (evt, input)=>{
    var input = document.getElementById('randomInput').value;
    ipcRenderer.send('input-broadcast', input);
});
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>Your input was <span id="userInput"></span><p>
        <button id="start">Open</button>
        <script>require('./renderer')</script>
  </html>
```

**enterValue.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter a name</p>
    <input type="text" id="randomInput" placeholder="enter a value"/>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <script>require('./renderer2.js')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call order is not right when sending input back to `renderer.js`. You call

```js
win.webContents.send('input-received', data)
```

when `index.html` is not yet re-loaded into `win`!

To fix this you should swap the calls and make sure that the content is ready when you send ipc message

```js
ipcMain.on('input-broadcast', (evt, data) => {
    console.log('input-broadcast happened in main')
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))
    win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
        win.webContents.send('input-received', data)
    })
})
```